# How can i put counter of leave in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, counter

Here in username it will fetch data from collection of mongodb, but in ***Total leave in this month*** I want to put counter in this month employee take how many leaves?

```
<form id="myform" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ url('approve-leave', $leaves->id) }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-md-6"><strong> Employee Name</strong></label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{$leaves->username}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-md-6"><strong> Total Leave in this month </strong></label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            1
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

So, anyone please help me how canI do that?

Comment: is `$leaves` a collection

Comment: Yes, It is collection

Comment: I'm wondering how did you access username from a collection like this. `{{$leaves->username}}`

Comment: Sorry collection name is leavemanagement
and I wrote code like this in controller  `$leaves = LeaveManagement::find($id);
        return view('pages.leavelist', compact('leaves', 'id'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have same problem as mine. I solved this problem using below approach.
First I created separate table for year_wise_use_leave. In that table I increment count on every month using crone job. And directly displayed monthly available leave from that table.

And for approve/reject action will be directly reflected in that table. so if you want to fetch yearly user's leave that it will be easy at that time.

When user's yearly leave is entered than you have to divide it by 12 and store it in year_wise_use_leave table.

Here is my crone job code

```
$userLeaves = UserAdditionalDetail::select('id', 'user_id', 'total_leaves')->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
        $query->where('deleted_at', null);
    })->get();

    foreach ($userLeaves as $userLeave) {
        $yearlyLeave = YearWiseUserLeave::where('user_id', $userLeave->user->id)->where('is_expired', 0)->first();
        $yearlyLeave->total_leave += $userLeave->total_leaves / 12;
        $yearlyLeave->save();
    }
```

Here UserAdditionalDetail is my table where user's yearly leave is stored.And this crone job is called on every month.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Owk great sir, I don't know much about Crone job, but I'll look forward to it. Thankq so much

Comment: crone job is nothing but one type of script which is called automatically when server is running

Comment: ya I know the basic concept but how to implement in code, I am unaware with that stuff so i am reading documentation,